# Can we use entangled black holes to form wormholes?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-entanglement, wormholes, quantum-teleportation

If any object can be made black hole by crushing it to its Schwarzschild radius, can we do the same process in two different points in the space keeping the quantum states of both the objects entangled and, thus, make a wormhole?

Comment: Why do you think entanglement would make a wormhole? Note that general relativity does not recognise entanglement as a source of curvature of space-time, so  GR alone does not predict any wormhole spacetime.

Comment: I believe what you are think about is the ER=EPR conjecture. Try a google search on this and you'll find more information about it.